# didn't write data in google sheet in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-sheets, next.js

am new stuck with a problem, am not able to write data in google sheet , read data from google sheet is working fine, can anyone try to tell me where am wrong please try to fix my code. If you have any question please free feel to ask any time.

[image: Error Image]

[image: Error]

> sheet.js

```
import { google } from 'googleapis';

export async function getDataFromSheets() {
  try {

    const target = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];
    const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(
      process.env.GOOGLE_SHEETS_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      null,
      (process.env.GOOGLE_SHEETS_PRIVATE_KEY || '').replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
      target
    );

    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: jwt });
    const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId: process.env.SPREADSHEET_ID,
      range: 'sheet'
    });

    const rows = response.data.values;

    const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
      spreadsheetId: process.env.SPREADSHEET_ID,
      range: 'sheet',
      valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
      requestBody: {
        values: [['']],
      }
    })

console.log(res)


    if (rows.length) {
      return rows.map((row) => ({
        title: row[0],
        description: row[1],
      }));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  return [];
}
```

> index.js

This is the index.js file. where we write our output code.

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

import { getDataFromSheets } from './libs/sheets'

export default function Home({ data }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Nextsheet </title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Connecting NextJS with Google Spreadsheets as Database"
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <h1>Welcome to Nextsheet </h1>
        <p>Connecting NextJS with Google Spreadsheets as Database</p>
        <ul>
          {data && data.length ? (
            data.map((item) => (
              <li key={item}>
                {item.title} - {item.description}
              </li>
            ))
          ) : (
            <li>Error: do not forget to setup your env variables </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
export async function getStaticProps(context) {

  const sheet = await getDataFromSheets();


  return {
    props: {
      data: sheet.slice(0, sheet.length), // remove sheet header
    },
    revalidate: 1, // In seconds
  };
}
```

Comment: About `not able to write data in google sheet`, when I saw your script, it seems that you want to append `[[""]]` to `sheet`. If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? For example, when an error occurs, can you provide the error message?

Comment: if i passed my here value then getting an error , Error is mentioned above in a picture. I want to add value on sheet, whatever i Wrote in [[""]] inside that.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your script and your additional image, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1):

When I saw your script, it seems that you use the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly`. In this case, the values can be retrieved. But, when the values are put, such an error showing in the image occurs. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const target = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];
```

#### To:

```
const target = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];
```

#### Reference

- [Scopes for Google Sheets API, v4](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#sheets)

Comment: thanks for giving your efforts, but in my case write data operation is not working, So can you try to fix my this error

Comment: @Monu Patil Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I test your script for appending the value using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`, no error occurs. I apologize for this. So can I ask you about the detailed information of your current issue? About `So can you try to fix my this error`, can you provide the error message?

Comment: Thank You So much for supporting me while running my application getting an error like                                                                                                                 
 Server Error
Error: Error serializing `.data[4].description` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.                           Please try to fix my error...You can also check top i have added my error picture

Comment: @Monu Patil Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question and replying, I cannot understand `Error serializing .data[4].description returned from getStaticProps in "/". Reason: undefined cannot be serialized as JSON.`. So can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? About your new issue, I would like to try to understand and think of a solution. I apologize for this.

Comment: i have attached error log image you can checkout

Comment: @Monu Patil Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from `i have attached error log image you can checkout`, I cannot understand your situation. So can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? About your new issue, I would like to try to understand and think of a solution. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thanks sir, giving your efforts, I Solved error